# build go project in Jenkins with dependencies in private repository

Tags: go, jenkins, credentials

I'm trying to set up automated build for `go` projects. Most people just use github dependencies which don't need credentials. We have some internal dependencies however available on our private git central server. Credentials are needed however to have go access these.

A possible workaround would be to configure a global git variable inside our build machines / build dockers; something like:

```
git config --global url."https://user:password@private.git.server/".insteadOf "https://private.git.server/"
```

however this doesn't seem to be the best solution to me, since the password would be stored in a human-readable text file.

I think the `git-credentials` plugin should be able to help me out; could I maybe export `GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1` and let the `git-credentials` plugin fill in for me?

How could I make sure `go get` or `go install` gets access to our private repository in a secure way?

Answer (score 1):

I use a workaround with GITHUB_TOKEN to solve this.

1. Generate `GITHUB_TOKEN` here https://github.com/settings/tokens
2. `export GITHUB_TOKEN=xxx`
3. `git config --global url."https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/mycompany".insteadOf "https://github.com/mycompany"`

This way you don't expose the password and can revoke token at any time.

Note: Go uses `http` when downloading dependencies, not `ssh`.

Comment: yes; I don't expose the password; but I expose the token which has about the same security risk, right?

Comment: Yes and no, Token has security risk, but you can define its access level. Also, you can store an encrypted version of it.